# método con linQ no exporta el archivo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto ASP.NET en MVC 4.0 y estoy usando linQ para tratar de exportar un excel y que el usuario pueda descargarlo.
La llamada al método desde la vista se ejecuta correctamente, depurando todo parece estar bien, pero no descarga el archivo.

la llamada:

```
$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Distribution/ImprimirExcel/',
                data: "hola",
                //cache: false,
                success: function () {

                },
                error: function (result) {

                },
            });
```

el método:

```
public async Task ImprimirExcel()
        {
            IList<Distribuciones> dist;
            dist = await Task.Run(() =>BBDDHelper.GetDistributionsGroup());
            var grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = from data in dist.OrderBy(x => x.id)
                              select new
                              {
                                  id_distribución = data.id,
                                  id_grupo = data.id_group,
                                  id_usuario = data.id_user,
                                  data.activa,
                              };

            grid.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=iDealConfig.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grid.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }
```

La primera vez que ejecuté el método si descargó el archivo.
He probado a borrar el archivo, pero sigue sin volverlo a descargar.
No da ningún tipo de error.

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo con un FileResult

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```